# SQL rank grouping variation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to achieve the following "rank" result given the original dataset composed by the column ID and CODE.

```
id   code   rank
1     A      1
2     A      1
3     A      1
4     B      2
5     B      2
6     C      3
7     C      3
8     C      3
9     A      4
10    A      4
```

Using the RANK_DENSE instruction over the CODE column i get the following result (with the A code getting the same rank value also after "the break" between the rows)

```
id   code   rank
1     A      1
2     A      1
3     A      1
4     B      2
5     B      2
6     C      3
7     C      3
8     C      3
9     A      1
10    A      1
```

Is it possible to achieve the results as shown in the first (example) table, with the A code changing rank when there is a separation between the group formed by id: 1-2-3 and the one formed by id: 9-10 without using a cursor?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'first ranking numeration'?

Comment: I'm referring to the first "table" example that I've posted (i will correct the  main post to be more specific)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sql 2012

Comment: You can have a look at my answer here (it is essentially the same question). You can simplifiy it considerably since `LAG` can be used in your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068001/rank-by-groups-sql-server/28070786#28070786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find sequences of values and give them a rank.  You can do this with a difference of row numbers approach.  The following assigns a different number to each grouping:

```
select o.*, dense_rank() over (order by grp, code)
from (select o.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by code order by id)
             ) as grp
      from original o
     ) o;
```

If you want the assignment in the same order as the original data, then you can order by the `id`, but that requires an additional window function:

```
select o.*, dense_rank() over (order by minid) as therank
from (select o.*, min(id) over (partition by grp, code) as minid
      from (select o.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by id) -
                    row_number() over (partition by code order by id)
                   ) as grp
            from original o
           ) o
     ) o;
```

Comment: Can you edit the second query you posted to allow the correct behavior? Adding the ordering on the min...over clause (from (select o.*, min(id) over (order by grp DESC, code ASC) as minid). Without the ordering all the "therank" was with classified as "1". Tell me what do you think.

Comment: @user3247900 . . . That should have been `partition by`.

Answer (score 1):

SUM by if current is the same as previous row. Works from SQL Server 2012.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id, code,
        CASE Code WHEN LAG(CODE) OVER (ORDER BY id) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Diff
    FROM Table1)
SELECT id, code, SUM(Diff) OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM CTE
```

Please also see similar question at [How to make row numbering with ordering, partitioning and grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146158/how-to-make-row-numbering-with-ordering-partitioning-and-grouping)